# PowerBI Incremental calculation

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, dax, formulas

I have this table:

```
Total_mb  used_mb  free_mb   Date
--------------------------------------
20000      2000     19000     1/28/2018
20000      1990     18290    1/12/2018
20000      1800     18200    1/6/2018
20000      1800     18100    1/1/2018
```

The idea would be to select two different dates and then get the subtraction between them and use that value in a visual.

So, how can I get the incremental information between two dates. (The table is only illustrative )

Comment: How are you selecting your dates?

Comment: i'm selecting in a graphic with a slicer. But i think that some kind of formula would be the ideal. Don't know how to do it or for when start. @AlexisOlson